# Recurrence Relation: Finding Big O

Tags: big-o, recurrence

I'm trying to find Big O of this recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n^c // where c is >=1
```

So I decided to solve this by using a recursion tree, which I have broken down as follows:

```
n^c -> (n-1)^c -> (n-2)^c -> ... -> (n-i)^c
```

I then formed the following sum:

```
from 0 to n-1:
   (n-i)^c
```

Reducing this sum gives:
`(n-(n-1))^c = (1)^c`

So then would the correct Big O notation be **O(n)**? Thanks.